# How to use NSRange

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsrange

I am using NSRange with an Attributed string, but I don't fully understand which parts of the text will be bolded and which are not. This is what I tried:

```
NSRange boldedRange = NSMakeRange(2, 4);
```

What exactly does the 2 stand for and the 4 stand for?

Thanks in advance for anyone who contributes to this post

Comment: http://nshipster.com/nsrange/

Comment: ⌥-click on the symbol to see its declaration. `location` is 0-based.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It says as:

```
NSMakeRange(<#NSUInteger loc#>, <#NSUInteger len#>)
```

So in your case:

```
NSRange boldedRange = NSMakeRange(2, 4);
```

2 is the starting location.

4 is the character count till what it will use.

Ex. If you use `boldedRange` on TYPEWRITER, it will change it to TY**PEWR**ITER

Comment: With the standard warning: ranges apply to a UTF-16 encoding so oddities may occur with strings that include far-from-Latin characters (emojis being an example you may encounter regardless of language). I can tell you from first-hand experience that putting a colour change within an emoji caused CoreText to hang indefinitely under iOS 4; I doubt that exact problem persists but a mid-glyph colour change doesn't make any sense so something other than your intention would have to happen.